# navigationController?.pushViewController not working in child view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Pushing another View Controller when my ChildVC is pushed results in a frozen screen, but GrandchildVC calls `viewDidLoad`. Am I misunderstanding how to use UINavigationController?

**Hierarchy of app**

UINavigationController

- Root VC

  - Child VC

    - Grandchild VC

In `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainController)
navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
navigationController.setNeedsUpdateOfHomeIndicatorAutoHidden()

self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

In `RootVC.swift`:

```
func pushedDisplayChildButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
     navigationController?.pushViewController(ChildVC(), animated: true)
}
```

This works, and subsequently pushes and displays ChildVC.

In `ChildVC.swift`:

```
func pushedDisplayGrandchildButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
     navigationController?.pushViewController(GrandchildVC(), animated: true)
}
```

This doesn't work -- while it pushes GrandchildVC() to the stack, it fails to display it and freezes the app (although GrandchildVC does call `viewDidLoad`). What's going on? Why isn't GrandchildVC displaying after it's pushed?

I should mention that calling `navigationController?.present(viewControllerToPresent: GrandchildVC(), animated: true, completion: nil)` works, but `pushViewController` does not.

Result of `expr -l objc++ -O -- [UIViewController _printHierarchy]` is:

```
<UINavigationController 0x103824a00>, state: appeared, view: <UILayoutContainerView 0x103611130>
   | <MyApp.RootVC 0x103611e40>, state: disappeared, view: <UIView 0x10370ae10> not in the window
   | <MyApp.ChildVC 0x104806360>, state: disappearing, view: <UIView 0x104c051e0>
   | <MyApp.GrandchildVC 0x104806b60>, state: appearing, view: <UIView 0x104c07440> not in the window
```

Comment: Please show context, not mere single lines of code. Timing is everything. For example “In ChildVC.swift” _where_?

Comment: @matt Just updated.

Comment: Well, sorry but there isn’t anything about the code you’ve shown that would explain it. What I mean is, I can easily make an example project that does everything you’ve mentioned and works fine. So the problem lies elsewhere. You say it pushes the grandchild onto the stack; how do you know? Sounds to me like the problem is that the grandchild’s view is transparent, or something, so you can’t see it.

Comment: @matt When I do ```print(navigationController?.viewControllers)```, it prints GrandchildVC. That's how I know it pushed. It's not a transparent view (as it works correctly when calling ```presentViewController```.

Comment: Johnny, you’re using the terms “child” and “grandchild”. FWIW, the term “child” has a very specific meaning in iOS, namely view controller containment. I’m inferring that this is not what you’re doing here, but rather just pushing one vc after another.

Comment: If your “grandchild” is being instantiated the exact same page for both presenting and pushing and looks fine for the former and not the latter, then I wonder if there’s something weird going on with your view controller hierarchy. Run your app, push all the way to the “grandchild”, hit the “pause” button, and at the `(lldb)` prompt enter `po [UIViewController _printHierarchy]` (or, if pausing in a Swift frame, enter `expr -l objc++ -O -- [UIViewController _printHierarchy]`). Edit your question to include what the view controller hierarchy looks like.

Comment: It should look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/MG4MT.png

Comment: @Rob just edited. My GrandchildVC has the state ```appearing``` but is ```not in the window```. You're correct in that I'm using the terms ```child``` and ```grandchild``` in a different way.

Comment: Yes, the fact that child is stuck on disappearing and grandchild is stuck on appearing is really interesting. That definitely suggests that my transparent theory is wrong (as you already argued very well). But I still believe that the _reason_ we are stuck is somewhere outside the code you showed, because, as I said, I can show you a project where it all just works as you would expect.

Comment: @Rob and matt Figured it out. Was doing a custom animation to transition between ViewControllers and got caught in there. Thanks for all your help. It is much appreciated.

Comment: I’m glad you solved it. If you think your realization would be helpful to future readers, feel free to [post an answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). If not (or if you don’t want to go through that), you might as well just delete this question.